# Where should I install myproj-config.cmake and myproj-version-config.cmake?

Tags: installation, cmake, libraries, dependency-management, build-dependencies

Suppose you're developing some library, `myproj`, using CMake for build configuration; supporting the `cmake --install` (using `install()` commands); and supporting use of `myproj` with CMake config mode, i.e. by making relevant `.cmake` files accessible to dependent projects.

Now, ,given an install root directory - where should I install my project's configuration `.cmake` files? Is there an idiomatic standard(ish) location?

- Sorush Khajepor's R&D blog [suggests](https://iamsorush.com/posts/cpp-cmake-config/) `${LIB_INSTALL_DIR}/cmake/myproj` - and it's the newest.
- Foonathan's blog [suggests](https://www.foonathan.net/2016/03/cmake-install/) placing the config `.cmake` files in `${LIB_INSTALL_DIR}/`. So does [Falkor's blog](https://www.f-ax.de/dev/2020/10/07/cmake-config-package.html).
- The documentation [page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakePackageConfigHelpers.html) for the `CMakePackageConfigHelpers` module suggests: `${LIB_INSTALL_DIR}/myproj/cmake`.

What's the most popular/idiomatic choice? And what are its pros and cons relative to the other ones?

Comment: The adoption term of CMake is too young and undeveloped to have idiomatic ways for many things, that in your question included. I just checked where my `make install` ended up with GTest, fmt & boost: all of them ended up in `${LIB_INSTALL_DIR}/cmake/project`. So I'd follow the steps of these popular libs. They also chose a pretty reasonable path.

Answer (score 1):

I advocate for setting a cache variable to override this and defaulting it to `<LIBDIR>/cmake/ProjName` (as you suggest in your answer):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)  # for saner CACHE variables
project(ProjName VERSION 0.1.0)

# ...

include(GNUInstallDirs)
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)

set(ProjName_INSTALL_CMAKEDIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/ProjName"
    CACHE STRING "Path to ProjName CMake files")

install(EXPORT ProjName_Targets
        DESTINATION "${ProjName_INSTALL_CMAKEDIR}"
        NAMESPACE ProjName::
        FILE ProjNameConfig.cmake
        COMPONENT ProjName_Development)

write_basic_package_version_file(
    ProjNameConfigVersion.cmake
    COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion)

install(FILES
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ProjNameConfigVersion.cmake"
        DESTINATION "${ProjName_INSTALL_CMAKEDIR}"
        COMPONENT ProjName_Development)
```

I wrote a blog post with an expanded version of this a while back: https://alexreinking.com/blog/building-a-dual-shared-and-static-library-with-cmake.html

In general, setting an `install()` destination to *anything* other than `"${SOME_CACHE_VARIABLE}"` is bound to cause headaches for *some* package maintainer. Where `GNUInstallDirs` doesn't provide a valid configuration point, you must create your own.

Comment: What's that about "saner cache variables"?

Comment: @einpoklum - https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0126.html

Comment: So, this does something weird with `ProjName_INSTALL_CMAKEDIR`. I get: `lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/cuda-api-wrappers`, while when installing, the libraries are under `lib`, not `lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll argue in favor of `${LIB_INSTALL_DIR}/cmake/myproj`.

If you're installing to some library-specific install location, e.g. `/opt/myproj` - then it doesn't *really* matter all that much anyway. But think about what happens when you install to, say, `/usr/local`.

- If you place the scripts in `${LIB_INSTALL_DIR}`, that library now becomes full of `foo-config.cmake` and `foo-version-config.cmake`, instead of just library files (and some subdirs). Less fun for browsing and searching.
- If you place the scripts in `${LIB_INSTALL_DIR}/myproj/cmake`, then - the same thing happens, but with per-project subdirs instead of sets of files. Better, perhaps, but instead - why don't we just replace the path elements of `myproj` and `cmake`, and that way we would get a `cmake/` directory with many subdirs, instead. That's cleaner and more convenient IMHO.